# DIV width doesn't reflect on all browsers despite 100% value and universal reset

Tags: css

I want my whole html file to fit within the 1020 width resolution, with all elements at the center, but I want my footer to have a top and bottom border spanning the whole 100% of my page no matter what the resolution. So I made a wrapper div with a 1000px width to contain most of my body elements except the footer. The footer I set to 100% width.

I have reset all universal values at the start of my css file. However, I still get a padding at my left part and a scroll bar - the border doesn't go all the way through the left. I don't get it! What should I do?

Comment: Some code or a link to a test page would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a reset?

Meyer reset -

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Yahoo reset -

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/